# Is it possible to run desktop applications on Google Colaboratory?

Tags: persistence, google-colaboratory, desktop-application, remote-server, vnc

I would like to run desktop applications (for debug and research purposes) on a Google Colab notebook.
Is that possible?

Comment: why has this question been downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [GNU Colab](https://github.com/tallero/GNUColab).

With it you can easily have a whole persistent desktop environment running on top of a Colaboratory VM instance.

Here's a [video demonstration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l1X2Cfg-330).